# How to read XML data and bind to MVC model or return jsondata and bind the particular columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, xml-parsing

I have one XML, where i need to display in jqGrid using MVC, below is my `ErrorLogcollection`.

I want to read every bit of value where XML element is there and get the data to display in jqGrid in `cshtml` page.

I want few columns to be bind to JqGird like ErrorLog (CorrelationId, ErrorType), Message (Error),Device (DeviceId, Type) Location (Latitude, Longitude)
   So what needs to be done in MVC Controller to get this columns and bind to jqGrid(cshtml) view page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ErrorLogCollection xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xxxx/xxxxx/Inbound/Error">
  <HasNextPage>false</HasNextPage>
  <Nav>
    <Link rel="self" methods="GET" href="https://t21-data.tss/xxxx/Error/Device/99F10001?fromDate=2016-02-09T04:45:00.000Z&toDate=2016-02-09T05:22:34.459Z"/>
  </Nav>
  <ErrorLog>
    <CorrelationId>724397918</CorrelationId>
    <ErrorType>Origin Validation</ErrorType>
    <ErrorMessages>
      <Message>
        <Error>
          Device of Type: PLE631 and DeviceId 99F10001 is not identifiable..
        </Error>
        <Header>
          <Origin>
            <Device>
              <DeviceId>99F10001</DeviceId>
              <Type>PLE631</Type>
            </Device>
          </Origin>
          <TimestampUtc>2016-01-21T05:22:34.459Z</TimestampUtc>
        </Header>
        <Blocks>
          <Location>
            <Latitude>-20.593684</Latitude>
            <Longitude>78.96288</Longitude>
            <IsValid>true</IsValid>
            <PrecisionKilometers>100</PrecisionKilometers>
          </Location>
          <MachineSecuritySystemOperatorID>
            <ID>6578</ID>
            <FirstName>MSSFirstName</FirstName>
            <LastName>MSSLastName</LastName>
            <Description>Chennai</Description>
            <KeyValue/>
          </MachineSecuritySystemOperatorID>
        </Blocks>
        <PayloadCorrelationId>724397918</PayloadCorrelationId>
      </Message>
    </ErrorMessages>
    <InsertUtc>2016-02-09T05:22:21.633Z</InsertUtc>
    <PayloadUrl>
      https://xxxxx/xxx/Payload/724397918/
    </PayloadUrl>
  </ErrorLog>
  <ErrorLog>...</ErrorLog>
  <ErrorLog>...</ErrorLog>
  <ErrorLog>...</ErrorLog>
  <ErrorLog>...</ErrorLog>
  <ErrorLog>...</ErrorLog>
</ErrorLogCollection>
```

---

### cshtml code & Javascript Code

function getDataInSearchResult() {

```
$('#jQGrid').jqGrid({


    search: true,       
    multiboxonly: true,
    colNames: ["PayloadCorrelationId", "Export", "ErrorType"],

    colModel: [
        { name: 'ErrorLogCollection.[ErrorLog][CorrelationId]', Index: 'ErrorLogCollection.[ErrorLog][CorrelationId]', width: 120 },
         { name: "Export", editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", width: 45, sortable: false, align: "center", formatter: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "1:0" }, formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
          { name: 'ErrorLogCollection.[ErrorLog][ErrorType]', index: 'ErrorLogCollection.[ErrorLog][ErrorType]', width: 100 }],

    cellEdit: true,
    pager: jQuery('#divpager'),
    rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
    sortorder: "desc",
    datatype: 'json',
    viewrecords: true,
    mtype: 'GET',
    gridview: true,
    url: '/DataIn/DataInSearchResult/',


});
$("#jQGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#divpager',
              {add:false,edit:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false},
              {},
              {},
              {},
               { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, showQuery: true }
             );



 }
```

---

### MVC Code

public JsonResult DataInSearchResult(string ddlDSVIN, string search, string OEMType, DateTime? frmDate = null, DateTime? toDate = null)
        {
            XDocument xmlResponse = null;
            string strJsonTest = null;
            string resourceURI = string.Empty;
            xmlResponse = GetMongoErrorForAssetOrDevice("1", "99F10001", "CAT", frmDate, toDate);
            ErrorLogCollection errorLogCollec = new ErrorLogCollection();

```
      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ErrorLogCollection));
      Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
      using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
      {
          xmlResponse.WriteTo(xw);
      }
      ms.Position = 0;
      errorLogCollec = (ErrorLogCollection)serializer.Deserialize(ms);



        //if (xmlResponse != null)
        //{
        //    DataTable dt = null;
        //    var jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject<ErrorLogCollection>(xmlResponse);
        //    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        //}
        //else
            return Json("No Error's Found", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


     }
```

Now please check this and response to my query....

I want to read and bind it to jqGrid, can you please let me how to do the process.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is formulate in too common way. All sounds like the requirement to implementation. It seems that you don't have neither ASP.NET MVC code nor JavaScript code which uses jqGrid. The XML data seems exists on the backend and you need first to read the data. You write "i need to display in jqGrid" event without the description of the columns of the grid which you want to display. Sorry, but one can't write all the code for you. In general if some MVC method returns exactly the data then you can use `xmlReader` and `xmlmap` of `colModel` to display the data in jqGrid.

Comment: Just asking how to map xml elements and bind to jqGrid, I have pasted my complete code...I am facing problem how to navigate each and every element of xml and take only required elements from xmlResponse and send it to JqGrid and bind it... I am not asking for complete code......if any one know the solution pls reply it.